# maven error transferring file blacklisted

Tags: maven, nexus, artifacts

i cannot download artifacts from my nexus server through maven but i can access the urls from my browsers without proxy. I am getting

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:connect
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect...
    Repository will be blacklisted
```

I am using maven 2.2.1

Comment: Please, post relevant information (or whole) from your pom.xml and your settings.xml

Comment: Sorry. Im posting in stack through my phone. Javascript is disabled in my machine as i cannot log in. I'll try to post more details when i access this on anothr pc

Comment: Hi. Does the solutions we provided helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn -U` to force updates, even if they are blacklisted.

Did you specify your repository in your `pom.xml`? It could be a DNS problem. Try to specify your repository with your IP instead of the hostname.

Comment: No.. i just added the repositories in the settings.xml in maven conf and .m2 folder and added the username and password of each repo in the <servers> section. Is it still needed in pom.xml of each module?

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to add repository credential in you settings.xml, if it require authentication (that you fulfill wia your browser, even whithout knowing it):

### Settings.xml :

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>corporate-nexus</id>
      <username>login</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

### pom.xml

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>corporate-nexus</id>
      <name>My Corporate repository</name>
      <url>http://url.to.your.repo.corp</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Be carefull, the id tags must have the same value.

Please add more information about your configuration if you want a more accurate answer

More information here : http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html